# Angular 5 - Manipulating HttpErrorResponse's error property in HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular5, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I have custom error message body as JSON from rest api.

```
{  
   "status":400,
   "url":"/api/abc",
   "message":"Custom Error Message"
}
```

I want to get it as object in subscribe's error scope. 
I tried to convert it to an object after every response using HttpInterceptor. But HttpErrorResponse is read-only. How can I obtain this object in service?

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                // Here trying convert to object from json
                err.error = <ErrorMessageBody>JSON.parse(err.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to grab the error during an intercept, and not just during a response?

Comment: Because I don't want to do the same process for every response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`err.error` is already translated to JSON.

This worked for me with `catch`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            return Observable.throw(err.error);
        });
}
```

Comment: I got mine working with your help. I had to use pipe due to a newer Angular version but it works, thanks :). "next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(...));"